# Find strings following a pattern in a text file using C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to search through a huge text file and extract a couple of strings that follow a pattern, then to write each of those strings into individual lines in another text file.

Is there an equivalent of Linux `grep` command, combined with the `*`, `-`, `^`, `[]`, etc. symbols in C# ?

I hope this is the place for this type of open questions. Thank you !

Comment: You know "re" of "grep" stands for "regular expression"? Also the top Google hits for "C# pattern match string" give plenty of results about regular expressions. And no, questions like this aren't quite suited for SO.

Comment: Yes; [`System.Text.RegularExpressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried to answer regexps... but it seems like directing OP to regular expressions is wrong ;) So I put here the same link to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Link Only answers are frowned upon as the link might die. Someone could have told you that though instead of just flyby down voting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm sorry I missed it

Comment: @TonyHopkinson In my case this is wrong. The answer is **regular expressions**. I turned the concept into a link, and if the link deads, the answer is still valid ;)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson In addition... see the other 2 answers where they're also link-based. At the end of the day, OP should hear *regular expressions* and this Q&A shouldn't be a guide on how to work with regular expressions after all. BTW, nowadays readers have their finger in the downvote icon before understanding the actual context of some given Q&A!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I didn't downvote you mate, and yep, some people seem to have a real hard on for it.

Comment: @DavidArno Right right... my answer pointed OP to regexps... You argument is vague.................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if it's a large file, use [`File.ReadLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to scan it as that lazy loads small amounts of data at a time, giving you one line at a time to process.

Then to match the items, you use [C#'s regular expression functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You'll likely end up with something like:

```
var regex = new Regex(-- your match expression --);
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("someFile").Where(line => regex.Match(line).Success)) 
{
    File.AppendAllText("file to write to", line + Environment.NewLine);
}
```